# Shuffle service now enabled by default in apache beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Without any changes on our side, our jobs using the python SDK for dataflow have started using the shuffle service:

[image]

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#using-dataflow-shuffle):

> To use the service-based Dataflow Shuffle in your batch pipelines, specify the following parameter:
> `--experiments=shuffle_mode=service`

However, we have **not** enabled this flag.

One major effect of this is the default size of the disk has gone from 250GB to 25GB on our workers. In one case, we ran out of disk space while the worker was starting up leading to a hung job never finishing.

Questions are:

- Is this a change in the underlying dataflow environment?
- Where do such changes get announced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Is this a change in the underlying dataflow environment?

  Yes, it is.
- Where do such changes get announced?

  I couldn't find any announcement of this change. But it should be updated [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#using-dataflow-shuffle). I'll make sure it's up-to-date.

Since Oct. 2020, batch jobs have began to opt into using Dataflow Shuffle by default. To opt out of using it, specify `--experiments=shuffle_mode=appliance`.

Comment: The public [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#using-dataflow-shuffle) has been updated.